# Не засчитывает на баланс переводы в сети ETH

Tags: ethereum

Установил ноду ефира и создал адрес с помощю `personal_newAccount` ну и конечно кинул для теста на сгенерированый адрес денег. Адрес- `0x11754F088d2C1D679D49D89dB402b87c609baB08` `https://etherscan.io/address/0x11754f088d2c1d679d49d89db402b87c609bab08` Отослал но ничего не пришло, тогда я разлочил акк(на всякий) и сделал еще одну транзу, но ничего опять не пришло.
состояние сети нормальное

```
eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 12800589,
  highestBlock: 12800705,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 12798108
}
```

Ну и я могу находить ету транзу в своей ноде но почему она не засчитала мне денег ето вопрос, может кто чем поможет?

Ноду запускаю `geth --cache=4096 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "web3,personal,admin,debug,db,net,eth,miner,rpc,txpool" --datadir /mnt/eth/eth/ --allow-insecure-unlock`

Версия и адрес кошеля на коибейс
`Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!  instance: Geth/v1.10.4-stable-aa637fd3/linux-amd64/go1.16.4 coinbase: 0xa48a480d86750093f51a7a4b21d0905fb6bbbef4`

Answer (score 0):

Вся причина была в том что нода небыла синхронизированая, для синхронизации пришлось увеличить ресурсы до 32RAM, 8CPU ну а ссд само собой у меня стоял, после синхронизации все заработало